# Why does running shellcheck from the demo flatpak work, but fail in Atom?

Tags: flatpak, atom-editor, shellcheck

I've installed [Atom from flathub](https://flathub.org/apps/details/io.atom.Atom). Now using the [linter-shellcheck](https://github.com/AtomLinter/linter-shellcheck) fails and says, the shellcheck command is not available.

However, if I [use the flatpak demo application](https://flathub.org/apps/details/org.flatpak.qtdemo) and use [`flatpak enter`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/500225/how-to-get-flatpak-enter-to-work/504144) to execute a shell inside of it, I can actually run `shellcheck` without any issues.
Howwever, the demo applications has much less permissions than the Atom's flatpak.

So how is this possible? Or, where is the error here?

[MY question here would be obsolete](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/412869/how-to-allow-gui-application-in-flatpak-to-run-cli-tool/422438) if it just orked to run `shellcheck` in the flatpak.

**Edit:**

*Inside* of the flatpak, here is where shellcheck and so on are:

```
$ which shellcheck
/usr/bin/shellcheck
$ echo $PATH      
/usr/share/Modules/bin:/app/bin:/usr/bin
```

(This is the demo flatpak, i.e. where I can execute it successfully.)

Comment: Where is `shellcheck` installed, and do you have that directory in your `$PATH`, and is that `$PATH` inherited by your Atom editor. This would depend on from where you launch Atom as well as where you set your `$PATH`.

Comment: I'll add it to the question.

Comment: I don't know what Atom inherits, I don't know the internals of flatpak to be sure to know this… (although I guess it is the same as in the demo flatpak, where it also did not inherit anything from the outside)